# Erro no "=" no mysqli_query

Tags: php, mysqli

Estou com um problema no *mysqli_query* e não consigo encontrar o erro.
Já tentei fazer algumas alterações que vi na internet e não adiantou.
Também tentei mudar a linha que está com problema de arquivo, porém o erro persistiu. A mensagem de erro é:

> [Thu Aug 17 11:57:43.192874 2017] [:error] [pid 2716] [client ::1:39160] PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '=' in /var/www/html/valida_login.php on line 7, referer: http://localhost/login.php

E a linha citada é:

```
result = mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM usuario WHERE login = '$usuario' AND senha = '$senha';");
```

Comment: Faltou o `$` no nome da variável? `result`?

Comment: Era isso mesmo, obrigado!

Comment: @rray postei como wiki pra fechar o assunto, mas se preferir podemos remover e vc reposta "oficialmente" para receber os devidos upvotes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Conforme resolvido pelo [@rray](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/91/rray) nos [comentários](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/229897#comment470737_229897), é erro de sintaxe.

Falta `$` na atribuição (para que o PHP saiba que se trata de uma variável):

```
$result = mysqli_query("SELECT ...
^
```